# Can't find children past a certain point using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to parse out the different configurations on the following web page:

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-3661

Specifically, I'm looking for data within the 'div' tags with ID's matching 'config-div-\d+'

I've tried running the following:

```
parsed = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-3661').content, 'html5lib')
configs = parsed.findAll('div', {'id' : re.compile('config-div-\d+')})
```

However, configs would always yield None. I've tried all of the parsers that were listed on the BeautifulSoup documentation page and they all yield the same result.

So I try only finding the parent node (div id="vulnCpeTree") and made sure I had the right one by manually drilling down from body.

```
parent = parsed.find('div', {'id' : 'vulnCpeTree'})
parent.findChildren()
[]
```

Is there a limit to the depth to which all of the parsers can parse? Is there a way to change this / work around this? Or did I miss something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of web-scraping you can use json feeds which can be found here, https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED

Comment: This webpage looks like it uses JS to load the results into the tables. That's why you aren't getting any results because BS4 doesn't wait for JS to finish loading. It simply retrieves the HTML file from the URL. If you "View page source" of the page in your browser, you'll see that those div id's aren't there either. That being said, it looks like the data is inside `<pre>` tags so `find_all` on `'pre'`. Alternatively, you can use selenium to scrape since it does wait for JS to finish loading, or use the JSON feed as @Sushanth had suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @Sushanth and @Scratch'N'Purr provided great answers for this question. @Sushanth provided the method that you're *supposed to* use when trying to stay up to date with vulnerabilities and @Scratch'N'Purr provided an explanation as to why I was experiencing the issues in the original question if I really wanted to go down the route of web-scraping.

Thank you both.